# prestashop and OSL 3.0: license for modules?

Tags: open-source, licensing, module, e-commerce, prestashop

I'm currently looking at [Prestashop](http://www.prestashop.com/), that uses an OSL 3.0 open source license. That license requires you to share the code even with users (so it plugs the famous "asp hole").

My question regards to it's [plugin architecture for modules](http://www.prestastore.com/). Would the OSL 3.0 license apply also to modules, or it wouldn't be considered part of the distribution.

I've already [read the license](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php) and searched for an explicit answer, but I haven't found it yet. Any insights?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Comment: I'm impressed. This question survived for almost 6 years unnoticed. Good job!

Answer (score 0):

Modules that are included in the main Prestashop distribution are subject to the same license, however any third-party modules or modules developed by Prestashop but not released in the main distribution can be subject to different license terms.

Each module can be written by a different developer/company and is subject to their own license terms. Modules can be free or commercial. Modules can be released under an Open Sourcee License (not necessarily OSL 3.0) or a bespoke license, a commercial license (could be perpetual or annual etc) or I've even seen case with no license details specified.

Also, modules do not have to be acquired from or purchased through the official marketplace they have developed (where Prestashop take a cut of the profits). They can be acquired direct from the software vendors, and installed easily by uploading a zip file.